# dependency injection in Arduino

Tags: dependency-injection, arduino

I've started working with Arduino and I want to do a time share system so I do not use the delay command.

I have a problem when I try to register objects that inherit from another.

Here I have a test code that should show in the terminal: "Wow wow Miuau miuau ..."

I have doubts when I try to create an Interface and how do I declare the register () function so that Cat and Dog objects can be entered in the Animal type Array.

The following code is only to show the problem:

```
class Animal {
  public:
    void message() {

    }
};

class Dog : public Animal {
  public:
  void message() {
    Serial.println("Guau guau");
  }
};

class Cat : public Animal {
  public:
  void message() {
    Serial.println("Miau miau ");
  }
};

class Multiplex {
  private:
    int index = 0;
    Animal objects[5];
  public:

  void register(Animal object) {
    objects[index] = object;
    index++;  
  }

  void go() {
    for(int i = 0;i<index;i++) {
      objects[i].message();
    }
  }

};

Dog dog;
Cat cat;
Multiplex multiplex;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  multiplex.register(dog);
  multiplex.register(cat);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  multiplex.go();
  delay(1000);

}
```

Any help is welcome ...

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you have to use polymorphism (virtual methods). But it still won't work with so many copies of "registered" object into the Animal base class (it shows nothing because `Animal::message()` is called). You have to use pointers (or references - but it's not so easy in this case)

```
class Animal { // pure virtual class (abstract class)
  public:
    virtual void message() = 0; // The '= 0;' makes whole class "pure virtual"
 };

class Dog : public Animal {
  public:
  virtual void message() {
    Serial.println("Guau guau");
  }
};

class Cat : public Animal {
  public:
  virtual void message() {
    Serial.println("Miau miau ");
  }
};

class Multiplex {
  private:
    int index = 0;
    Animal * objects[5];
  public:

  void reg(Animal * object) { // pass pointer to the object
    objects[index] = object;  // object must be valid for whole time
    index++;
  }

  void go() {
    for(int i = 0;i<index;i++) {
      objects[i]->message();
    }
  }

};

Dog dog;
Cat cat;
Multiplex multiplex;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  multiplex.reg(&dog);
  multiplex.reg(&cat);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  multiplex.go();
  delay(1000);
}
```

If you don't like dynamic polymorphism, you have to use something like object type, switch and typecasting to its correct type.